# Android layout icon list for portrait and landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have been trying to find a way to make a layout for both  portrait and landscape at the same time, its a vertical link button list on portrait and horizontal link button list on  landscape , is there any way to do this without having to do two different layouts?

[image: image for the portrait layout]

[image: image for the landscape layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that jump to mind are:

Use `FlexboxLayout`. Using this you could just put your six items into a single layout and they would wrap to a new line whenever necessary. That might not be what you want, though, since it might leave you with three rows of two items, or maybe even one row with five items and then a second with one item. Still, it's a good library and something worth familiarizing yourself with.

Alternatively, you could use `GridLayout`. This viewgroup has an `android:columnCount` attribute that accepts an integer, which means you can use an integer resource here. For example:

```
<GridLayout
    android:columnCount="@integer/columns"
    .../>
```

And then you could define this resource in two places:

**`res/values/integers.xml`**

```
<integer name="columns">3</integer>
```

**`res/values-land/integers.xml`**

```
<integer name="columns">6</integer>
```

Comment: It worked, thank u so much, i used the integers option